# Add a view on top of all the Activities

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android Application. I want to be able to add one view by code, that is drawn in top of all the activities on the application.

I've tried to add it to the window manager:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
final WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager);
activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                mWindowManager.addView(layout, params);
```

However, adding it like this I face two problems:

1.The layout is still displayed when I exit my app.

2.The layout does not respont to Click events.

Is there another solution to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want this top view in each activity?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia To all the activities from my app. If I display a new activity I want to still be shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to manage the show/view of the view I've used the solution proposed by Gopal.
I've attached onStop and onResume events so that the view is hidden when exiting application.

For the click events, I've realized that the type toast does not respond to click events. Therefore I've changed the type

```
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
```

to

```
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
```

I've to add the following permision too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: I think TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT requires a user permission.

Comment: @GopalRao Yes, I've added it to the solution. Sorry but the TYPE_APPLICATION can't be used inside the WINDOW_SERVICE view.

Comment: @Mateu click is still not working for me, tried all the 3 flags.

Below is my code for the View:

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.addView(valueTV);

Comment: not work for me, in nexus 6p, android 7.1.1, just don't know why.

Comment: @DysaniazzZ: have you asked the user for Permission using the Permisssion rationale that was introduced in Marshmallow? Its probably not working because of that.

Comment: Very like your solution. But how to do that the activity below the view can still catch user clicks?

Answer (score 8):

change `LayoutParams` type from `TYPE_TOAST` to `TYPE_APPLICATION`, and delete previous flags I have suggested,

and create one `BaseActivity` for all activities in your app, in that Activity in `onResume()` add this View to `WindowManager` and in `onPause()`, remove that View like,

```
  windowManager.removeView(view);
```

Comment: This solves problem (1) but not (2). The added layout is still not responding to click events.

Comment: @goap-rao with the TYPE_APPLICATION I get the following android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: pass Activity reference when creating your top View. like 
new LinearLayout(Activity.this);

Comment: I've added on the question how I define my layout. I've tried to change the "null" of inflate method for a ViewGroup, but I'm getting the same BadTokenException error.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error I had tried through the service to display the overlay window. but if I pass TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY it will display even after an application is minimized. I just want to show during the app running only.

Answer (score 8):

1) Create BaseActivity which extends Activity.

2) Now your all activity should extends BaseActivity instead Activity

3) Override setContentView() method.

4) create blank vertical linearLayout in this method.

5) Add your topView in this layout

6) And then add inflated view in this linearlayout

7) And finally call super.setContentView(passLinearLayoutHere)

**How to Implement this ?**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int resId) {

        LinearLayout screenRootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        screenRootView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        screenRootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Create your top view here
        View topView = new View(this); // Replace this topview with your view 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View screenView = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        topView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                           //You will get onclick here of your topview in whatever screen it is clicked
            }
        });

        screenRootView.addView(topView);
        screenRootView.addView(screenView);

        super.setContentView(screenRootView);
    }

}
```

Comment: This will create a new view every time the user switches activities, it won't re-use the existing top view.

Comment: It is not possible to use same view object among activities because it's violate the oops concept that is one children can not have multiple parents. When view is attached to on activity is a child of that activity so other activity can not use the same view. So this is proper way to implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: Right, I just wanted to point out that this does not answer the question, it is a workaround that gets you almost there.

Comment: Amazing solution. :)