# Show an overlay on top of other android activity but both can get user interaction

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a Popup message covering a part of a activity below it, but still want to enable the user to interact with activity, without dismissing the popup.

For example: "No Internet" message, but a part of application still working.

It can be an activity, or a dialog, but the activities below it should still receive user clicks.

I succeed to achieve this by including the same XML in several activities and apply common logic; but want to make it an independent UI unit

Comment: DialogActivity...?

Comment: Does it leave the user to tap something below it, without dismiss it?

Comment: you can create a custom View which is initially hidden but appears only after certain action.

Comment: I have multiply activities, but do not want to include the view inside their XML (or programmatically), also when open another activity and going back this view will be re-shown, and need special logic in onResume().
That's what I currently wrote, but want to make independent topmost popup code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) for this purpose. For use of snackbar refer [Adding an Action to a Message](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html)

OR

If you need to add a view independent of the application scope then you might try adding view directly to window [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138546/when-adding-view-to-window-with-windowmanager-layoutparams-type-system-overlay)

Comment: "They *automatically disappear* after a timeout or *after user interaction elsewhere on the screen*, particularly after interactions that summon a new surface or activity. Snackbars can be swiped off screen."
But I need 1) to keep it visible, 2) disable user to dismiss it 3) enable user iteration with the rest of application window

Comment: And to pin it to screen-top

Comment: Snackbar is still the optimal solution. 1) Keep it visible -> Set length to indefinite 2) Disable dismiss: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031476/how-to-disable-snackbars-swipe-to-dismiss-behavior
3) Interaction is enabled by default

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking.
How to pin it to the window top?

Comment: But the snackbar will be referenced to the parent activity, isn't it? What will happen when user navigates to another activity? and goes back? I need something independent in the application scope

Comment: If you need to add a view independent of the application scope then you might try adding view directly to window. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976701/add-a-view-on-top-of-all-the-activities) link

Comment: Thank you, nice advice! But still the activity under the view does not receive user clicks

Comment: @patilmandar2007, your code in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138546/when-adding-view-to-window-with-windowmanager-layoutparams-type-system-overlay) make it working. Add it as answer to this post