# Android: how to create "application level" always-on-top view without special permissions?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve the behavior shown in this image:

[image]

So that the floating view is on top of every activity in the app (and ONLY inside the app).

I don't want it to be on top of any other apps, so it's NOT a **system overlay**.

I did a lot or research online, and all the implementations I found define this view as `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` or `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` when initializing its layout params, and this requires the permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`!

but I want it to be just a normal view inside my app.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Using jetpack navigation then the activity has the view

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976701/add-a-view-on-top-of-all-the-activities . I think what you ask for may be impossible without the permission. How do you feel about converting your activities to fragments and host them in a single activity (using jetpack navigation is basically the same, with less work, as @cutiko mentioned)? In that activity, you can put a view on top of the frameLayout that will host your fragments.

Comment: It's a large app with many activities and legacy complex code, refactoring to single activity is not a viable option

Comment: Then make a base activity that has the overlay and make every activity inherit from it

Comment: How to preserve the state of the floating view between activities? using a base activity

Comment: have a shared viewModel for the floating view?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, for now i implemented it using TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY and I'm considering rebuilding it with the base activity approach (although this has a challenge as there are other activities opening from libraries and components that I can't control), will post an answer when I figure it out

Comment: did you find any viable solution?